# Bash script udev play sound

Tags: linux, bash

I have a problem with my script. I added a rule which detect if a unique USB if plugged in. These part works fine. My idea was after I did some things on the stick, I make a sound so the user know when he can unplugged the stick.
I like to use espeak and tried it without the rule and it is working, but only without the trigger.
Here is my usb.sh:

```
echo "Pluged in" >>/tmp/usb.log
espeak "Backup done"
```

And here is the rule i added:

```
ACTION=="add",KERNEL=="sdb1", SUBSYSTEM=="block" ,ATTRS{idVendor}=="0951", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1666" ,RUN+="/home/user/usb/usb.sh"
```

Comment: I believe that when launched from the rules, the `PATH` is not the same.
Try to replace `espeak` by `/usr/bin/espeak`, and `echo` by `/bin/echo`

Comment: Didn't fix my problem still the same. Echo is working fine and writes. Also my other problem is my other stuff won't be trigger as well.

Comment: And, of course `/home/user/usb/usb.sh` has correct permissions, and `../user/..` isn't the actual value? And sorry, where did you add the "rule" too? (/full/path/please/to/file ;-)? ) . Good luck!

Comment: @shellter I swapped my actual username with user so don't worry ^^. I changes the permission of my file ```sudo chmod +x ./usb.sh```. I created a file in ```/etc/udev/rules.d/backup.rules```

Comment: Any luck resolving your problem? If you have figured it out, post an answer and after 48? hrs you can accept your own answer and gain valuable reputation points ;-). Sorry I can't help further with this. Good luck!